# UIlabel animation won't fit in the screen

Tags: swift, xcode, animation

This is a quiz app that asks questions and after being answered the next questions animates across the screen. The problem is that if the next question is a longer question it will go past the screen. I have the labels set as 2 lines.

```
func animateLabelTransitions(){

    // Animate the alpha
    // and the center X constraints
    let screenWidth = view.frame.width
    self.nextQuestionLabelCenterXConstraint.constant = 0
    self.currentQuestionCenterXConstraint.constant += screenWidth
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
                          delay: 0,
                        options: [],
                     animations: {
                                self.currentQuestionLabel.alpha = 0
                                self.nextQuestionLabel.alpha = 1

                                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                                },
                     completion: { _ in
                                swap(&self.currentQuestionLabel,
                                &self.nextQuestionLabel)
                                    swap(&self.currentQuestionCenterXConstraint,
                                    &self.nextQuestionLabelCenterXConstraint)

                                    self.updateOffScreenLabel()

                                    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to put this in your `layoutSubviews` method

```
self.currentQuestionLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.view.frame.width
```

Comment: See also: [`sizeThatFits`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622625-sizethatfits).